# Tomcat 6 and 7 dynamic web project eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to run a dynamic web project on localhost server. i.e (tomcat over eclipse). But it shows error 404.It cant find the `index.jsp` file. I have tried changing the port, rechecking the `web.xml`  but the error still persists. So what can be some other things which I should be doing for correcting this error.

this is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>My_Asap</display-name>


<!-- 
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>asap_pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 -->
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

this is my `index.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="<%=basePath%>">

        <title>My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
        <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
        <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    -->
    </head>

        <body>
             This is my JSP page. <br>

        <form action ="servlet/MyServlet">
        <input type="submit" value='send'>
        </form>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats your dir structure ? Where does index.jsp reside?

Comment: src->asappkg->myservlet
src->dao->db

web-inf->lib->web.xml
webinf->index.jsp

Comment: Move index.jsp out of web-inf folder.

Answer (score 0):

first go server tab in eclipse then follow below step:-

1>Right Click on Tomcat and then click Property

2>Click on switch location then ok.

3>double clicks on Tomcat

4> In server location tab select "Use Tomcat Installation " Option.

Then restart Tomcat